# Does PCI DSS allows/restrict bulk sending of cards?

Tags: pci-dss

Does PCI DSS allows/restrict bulk sending of cards? eg: Im buying gift cards for my 200 employees, can I have them delivered to my HR?

Are there addendums or restrictions on this?

Answer (score 0):

PCI DSS specifies standards for computer systems that deal with payment card data.  It doesn't specify anything about physical cards themselves (other than when they are part of a computer system) or their purchase or sale.

Thus, PCI DSS doesn't apply in this case.  There is no reason you cannot buy many gift cards, but of course your card issuer or the seller may consider this to be suspicious and decide whether or not they want to allow the purchase.  That is a matter of business practice and fraud detection, and not related to PCI DSS in any way.